# How to require manual entry of username at login?

Tags: windows, windows-10, login-screen

How can I require that the user has to know which username they want and manually have to type in the username they want to sign in to, instead of the lock screen where they can just choose a username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open an elevated Powershell and run:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\" -Name "DontDisplayLastUserName" -PropertyType DWord -Value 1 -Force
```

to switch back to the original behavior delete that key or set the value to 0

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\" -Name "DontDisplayLastUserName" -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force
```

this is the same as in previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm bad at this. Do you know what would be wrong if I paste that in and get this response?

New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\'
because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\HKLM...olicies\System\:String) [New-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.....

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I missed the colon after the HKLM, please try again.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help. Is this a registry value I'm changing? I get a new message that occurs when I run either of the commands above:

New-ItemProperty : The property already exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...olicies\System\:String) [New-ItemProperty], IOExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand

Comment: @Eric - I should really have tested this more before posting it. If they value already exists (which is possible) it needs the `-Force` switch. I added that, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the **account on setting** then 
select **family and other user**. If they have outlook account. 
You can add them.